# C user input sporadic invalid results

Tags: c, string, input, invalid-characters

Coding in C, I'm having an issue with user input. Sometimes, the input works and sometimes it doesn't.

Example run output from terminal:

```
dennis@MBP2021 Encryption % make
cc Gronsfeld_Cipher.c /Users/dennis/Documents/C/programs/DJSlibrary/cs50.c -o cipher
dennis@MBP2021 Encryption % ./cipher 

Please enter line to be encoded: This, however, is not the time.

You entered: This, however, is not the time. Length: 31

The message is:  This, however, is not the time.
The cipher is:   EZNH, SCVKOHZ, KF UFP GXF ONWX.
The decipher is: THIS, HOWEVER, IS NOT THE TIME.


dennis@MBP2021 Encryption % ./cipher

Please enter line to be encoded: This, however, is not the time, nor the place to have fun.

You entered: This, however, is not the time, nor the place to have fun. Length: 58
zsh: trace trap  ./cipher
dennis@MBP2021 Encryption %
```

code snippet:

```
char data[] = "Dummy";
int keys[] = {11, 7, 13, 10, 25, 9, 8, 3};  


// Do the stuff
int main(void)
{   
    // Get input from user
    char *string_input = NULL;
    size_t string_size = 250;
    ssize_t bytes_read;

    printf("\nPlease enter line to be encoded: ");
    string_input = (char *) malloc(string_size);
    bytes_read = getline(&string_input, &string_size, stdin);

    if(bytes_read < 2)
    {
        printf("\n\nNo input was entered. Program terminating.\n");
        printf("Error Code: 1\n\n");
        free(string_input);
        return 1; 
    }

    string_input[bytes_read-1] = 0; // Clear out the new line.
    
    printf("\nYou entered: %s Length: %ld\n", string_input, bytes_read-1);
    strcpy(data, string_input);
    free(string_input);

    // Get sizes
    int DataLen = strlen(data);
    int ks = sizeof(keys) / sizeof(keys[0]);

    printf("\nThe message is:  %s", data);
```

According to what I see on the terminal, it dies at the strcpy (I guess) The line **string_input[bytes_read-1] = 0; // Clear out the new line** is trying to remove the line feed at the end of the string input.  It never gets to the last printf. I don't understand why it worked with a small line (31 bytes) and not the 58 byte line. I tried to use debug in vscode, but it doesn't allow me to enter an input line. Something else I need to find out. Also, I'm new to C programming. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unrelated, but there's no need to explicitly allocate memory for `string_input`, [`getline`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getdelim.3.html) will do it for you. Also, you [should not cast the result of `malloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is very likely this statement:

```
strcpy(data, string_input);
```

Here you copy data into an array that can only hold six characters, null-terminator included.

When you create and initialize the `data` array you only make space for the string `"Dummy"`, nothing more.

If the input it longer than five characters, then that means you will write out of bounds of `data`, and have *undefined behavior*.

Set a specific size for the `data` array, one that is big enough to hold the largest input.

Or keep on using `string_input`, and don't use `data` at all.

Comment: Thanks, I thought that the strlcpy would fix that, not sure where I got that notion.. Also, I did remove the malloc as suggested by some programmer dude. Thanks! I really appreciate it.